# How to find the next row that have a value in column in a dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe such as:

```
id     info    date     group    label
1       aa     02/05        1        7
2       ba     02/05        1        8
3       cp     09/05        2        7
4       dd     09/05        2        8
5       ii     09/05        2        9
```

Every group should have the numbers 7, 8 and 9. In the example above, the group 1 does not have the three numbers, the number 9 is missing. In that case, I would like to find the closest row with a 9 in the label, and add it to the dataframe, also changing the date to the group's date.

So the desired result would be:

```
id     info    date     group    label
1       aa     02/05        1        7
2       ba     02/05        1        8
6       ii     02/05        1        9
3       cp     09/05        2        7
4       dd     09/05        2        8
5       ii     09/05        2        9
```

Comment: Can duplicates exist for one group?

Comment: @ko3 Yes, duplicates can exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Its good if you include what you have tried so far so keep that in mind. Anyhow for this question, breakdown your thought process into pandas syntax. Like first step would be to check what `group` do not have which `label` from `[8,9]`:

```
dfs = df.groupby(['group', 'date']).agg({'label':set}).reset_index().sort_values('group')
dfs['label'] = dfs['label'].apply(lambda x: {8, 9}.difference(x)).explode() # This is the missing label
dfs
```

Which will give you:

| group | date | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/05 | 9 |
| 2 | 09/05 | nan |

Now merge it with original on label and have `info` filled in:

```
final_df = pd.concat([df, dfs.merge(df[['label', 'info']], on='label', suffixes=['','_grouped'])])
final_df
```

| id | info | date | group | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 02/05 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | ba | 02/05 | 1 | 8 |
| 3 | cp | 09/05 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | dd | 09/05 | 2 | 8 |
| 5 | ii | 09/05 | 2 | 9 |
| nan | ii | 02/05 | 1 | 9 |

And prettify:

```
final_df.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index().assign(id=lambda x:x['index']+1).drop(columns=['index']).sort_values(['group', 'id'])
```

| id | info | date | group | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 02/05 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | ba | 02/05 | 1 | 8 |
| 6 | ii | 02/05 | 1 | 9 |
| 3 | cp | 09/05 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | dd | 09/05 | 2 | 8 |
| 5 | ii | 09/05 | 2 | 9 |